# ASPxPopupControl always in front of another ASPxPopupControl

Tags: asp.net, css, devexpress

**Desired behavior:**

- popup1 is 100x100
- popup2 is 50x50
- neither popup can be modal for my purposes.

When popup1 is shown popup2 should also be shown in front of it. I want popup2 to always be in front of popup1 but when I click on popup1 then popup2 is always moved behind popup1. When I say "in front" I mean that I want popup2 to always have a higher z-index (foremost) even when popup1 is the active popup.

**Attempts and info:**

I can see in the page markup that a single popup gets a z-index of 12000 by default.

I have tried using css to give each popup different z-index values like so:

```
.popup1{z-index:20000!important;}
.popup2{z-index:21000!important;}
```

I also tried it like this:

```
.popup1{z-index:11000!important;}
.popup2{z-index:12001!important;}
```

I also tried wrapping each popup in a div tag with similar css.

Each popups z-index is updated to 12002 depending on whether or not it is active or not and this is regardless of what I set it to.

I also tried wrapping the larger popup in a div tag and handling the onclick event to set the z-index of the smaller popup.

Thanks in advance!

Some semi-related links:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q346044.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q382392.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q36091.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I tried wrapping popup1 (rear) in a div that handled the onclick event to bring popup2 (front) to the front but that did not work.

What did work was to handle the onmousedown event of the div wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke popup2 [BringToFront](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupControlBase_BringToFronttopic) method in popup1 [Shown](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPopupControlScriptsASPxClientPopupControlBase_Showntopic) event.

```
<dxpc:ASPxPopupControl ClientInstanceName="popup1"...>
    <ClientSideEvents Shown="
        function(s, e) { 
            if(e.window.index == 0) popup1.BringWindowToFront(popup1.GetWindow(1))
        }"/>
</dxpc:ASPxPopupControl>
```

This sample works with one popup control containing two windows. If that isn't your case (maybe you have two popup controls with one window) just adapt sample to your needs.

Comment: This did not work for me but it did help me to solve the problem.